# Lightweight M2M server deployment?

Tags: eclipse, iot, m2m, oma

1. Is there recommendation concerning the deployment of lwm2m server, should it be in the cloud or on a local gateway?
2. Can a lwm2M server be deployed on a constraint device, a Raspberry pi for example?
   if yes is there an existing implementation for it?

   I found the following implementation but I dont know if I can try them on RPi:

   - [leshan](https://github.com/eclipse/leshan)
   - [wakaama](https://github.com/eclipse/wakaama)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Wakaama and Leshan should work on a Raspberry